# Using GCD to speed up the loading of view

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

So, I got a monster code at my viewDidLoad on my first view. Well I am allocating 7 of my own objects, so it looks like this

```
OwnObject *o1 = [[OwnObject alloc] initWithValuesString:@"blabla" image:[UIImage named:@"blabla"]];
OwnObject *o2 = [[OwnObject alloc] initWithValuesString:@"blabla" image:[UIImage named:@"blabla"]];
```

And so on...

I was watching a session video once again at apple developer and they said that I should use GCD to speed things up, so could I speed my app by putting that to dispatch queue?

Note that my view loading isn't very slow, but I am just wondering should I usually put things like that in dispatch queue.

Thanks, sorry if this is stupid.

Comment: If it's fast enough loading the images synchronously, why bother doing it in the background?

Comment: I was just wondering should I generally do those kind of things in the background?

Comment: I typically perform network operations in the background using GCD. Object creation as you're showing here is typically lightweight enough to do on the main thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If those allocations don't do things which require the main thread (e.g. touching the UI) then they could be done via GCD in a queue. You'd want to use `dispatch_async`, because with a synchronous call you'd still have to wait until the allocations completed and would gain nothing. Also, you'd need to be sure that your view controller was designed to handle finishing `viewDidLoad` without having those objects allocated yet, since the async dispatch call would be, well, asynchronous. You would probably either need to post a notification that allocation had completed or use `dispatch_group_notify` so that the view controller would know when the allocations were complete and could start using the objects.

Unless these allocations take a long time, this is likely to be more trouble than it's worth.